# Javascript find all text except those in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a div, and this div can (or cannot) have html elements as children. With my javascript, i need to find all the occurrences of a word inside this div, except for those in the `<a>` tag.

For example:

```
<div id="dictionable">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="#lorem">lorem</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <p>lorem</p>
</div>
```

I tried with my ultra low capabilities to build a regex, failing miserably.
So I googled and found this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('(lorem)(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*</)', 'gim');
```

this regex finds every occurrence of "lorem" but not in EVERY tag.
I just need to exclude only the A tag.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: don't parse html with regex http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: Is jQuery an option?

Comment: ok for jquery.
I love Jeff Atwood's humor :D

Comment: jQuery or plain JS, the point is the same - regex is not suitable for querying the DOM. There are built-in functions that allow to traverse the DOM safely and accurately, as in Niet's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No regex. Absolutely no regex. Nuh-uh. Nope.

```
var copy = document.getElementById('dictionable').cloneNode(true),
    links = copy.getElementsByTagName('a'), l = links.length, i;
for( i=l-1; i>=0; i--) {
    // always work in reverse order when deleting stuff, it's safer!
    links[i].parentNode.removeChild(links[i]);
}

var result = copy.textContent || copy.innerText;
```

Boom!

Comment: That's a good starting point. I dont need to remove the tag, just ignore them when appear.

Comment: I like your approach. But any reason not to prefer `document.querySelectorAll` over `document.getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: @Valerio You are removing (i.e. ignoring) them only in a *copy* of the of the original parent `div`. Note the usage of of the `cloneMode` method.

Comment: @Boaz `getElementsByTagName` has been around a *lot* longer than `querySelectorAll`. This answer's code should work even in ancient IE versions. Also, you'd think the variable name `copy` would've been a clue XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Indeed it would. But even as an old-timer I would prefer promoting newer and better methods than outdated and officially unsupported IE versions :) Many people learn from these examples and follow suit. Anyway, voted this up of course.

Comment: @Boaz I don't see a point in using new stuff just for the sake of using new stuff. Is there any benefit to using `querySelectorAll` here?

Comment: @Boaz: ok for the copy, but after that how I can use the text back?

Comment: @Valerio The `result` variable contains your text. Do with it what you will.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Regarding `document.querySelectorAll`, the benefit is IMHO the fact that the selector is no longer limited to a very narrow set of element types, tags in this instance. With this method the selector can be refined and expanded in mere seconds without ever having to change anything else in the snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Using jquery its too simple

```
var $dictionable = $("#dictionable").clone();
$dictionable.find('a').remove();//This will remove all <a> tag
$dictionable.text();//This will give all text
```

Comment: This is destructive to the original. Bad.

Comment: Cloning the parent `div` with `.clone()` would improve this answer tremendously.

Comment: Yup - the jQuery code is much shorter to write, but [*much* slower to run](http://jsperf.com/so-27503019) ;)

Comment: Chaining jQuery's methods, you can even shorten this to a one-liner: `$("#dictionable").clone().find('a').remove().end().text();`

Comment: Sorry for being such idiot. I want to manipulate the div to find some text and do something (for example, wrap a tag around it). I dont want to remove any tag, just ignore the a tag when it appears.

Comment: @Valerio The two answers here show how to get all of the text in the `dictionable` div except the text in `a` elements, so that you can use that to find all the occurrences of a particular string (since that's what you said you wanted to do). If you actually have more specific requirements beyond that, I suggest creating a new question (and taking care to be more specific in the future).

Answer (score 0):

Since everything in an element is considered as an element by itself, you can simply iterate through the div's children.

Granted, it's not the shortest solution due to its validation, but it should be relatively fast.

```
var d = document.getElementById('dictionable');
var textcontent = '';
for (node in d.childNodes) {
    // accept only element (1), text (3) and non-link element
    if ((d.childNodes[node].nodeType != 1 && 
        d.childNodes[node].nodeType != 3) || 
        d.childNodes[node].nodeName == 'A')
        continue;

    textcontent = textcontent+d.childNodes[node].textContent
}
```

This was you can even set the search inside the loop and narrow the results down to a single element level.

Comment: This only iterates through `dictionable`'s immediate children. Some of those children could contain `<a>` elements. (And BTW, not all of an element's children are elements; only those with `nodeType === 1` are elements).