# javascript surround text in div

Tags: javascript, regex

following the suggestion of JLRishe in my previous question

[Javascript find all text except those in <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503019/javascript-find-all-text-except-those-in-a-tag)

I create a new request, just to clear up what I need to achieve.
I have a html document which contains something like this.

```
<div id="dictionable">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
     <br/><br/>
     <a href="#lorem">lorem</a>
     <br/><br/>
     <p>lorem</p>
</div>
```

What i need to conquer is to find all occurrences of a word (for example "lorem") and wrap it with a tag.
**I want to exclude the A tags** because they are links and do not match my needs.

In my previous question i learned how regex are bad. Any help using DOM?

I'm using jquery in this project, so feel free to use it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Iterate `childNodes` one by one, check if a node is an element or text node. If `a`, then ignore. From elements/text nodes find the wanted text, and wrap for example using select/range interface.

Comment: what i get is that you want to wrap the texts of each node except `a` tag inside `div` .Right ??

Comment: Yes, i need to wrap a tag around a specific word in a text. But if this word is in a link, i want to ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding my own way to achieve this:

```
 var base = $('#container');

    replace(base);

    function replace(container) {
        $(container).contents().filter(function () { return !$(this).is('a') && ($.trim($(this).text())) !== '' }).each(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === 1) return replace(this);

            if (this.nodeType === 3) {
                var text = $.trim($(this).text());
                var pattern = new RegExp(this, 'gim');
                text = text.replace(pattern, '<a href="#' + this + '">' + this + '</a>');
                $(this).replaceWith(text);
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
```